# Add _source to a BoolQueryBuilder Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

```
GET working-alias/_search
{
  "_source": "required-attribute" ,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match": {
            "key": "keyvalue"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to build above query in Java using BoolQueryBuilder. I am able to get the query part with the code below. However, I need only certain fields to be returned by the query which requires for me to add "_source". I couldn't find a function within BoolQueryBuilder which allows me to add "_source" with required fields to be returned to the overall query.

```
final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(KEY, queryValue));
```

Comment: Please the full code

Comment: Add full code which exactly explains the problem you have asked

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to wrap queryBuilder in a SearchSourceBuilder. SearchSourceBuilder will allow for adding sources using `.fetchSource`

```
final BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(KEY, queryValue));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder =
                    new SearchSourceBuilder().query(queryBuilder).fetchSource(fieldIAmLookingFor, null);
```